# Kafka consumer 100% cpu usage

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer which has been running for few days perfectly. Yesterday the broker went down. Since then the consumer is showing 100% cpu usage. The usage went down considerably (under 10%) when the broker was up. **I am curious why the usage is 100% (or near 100%) when broker is down? I don't see anything in the logs.**

- Kafka broker/server: 0.8.2.1
- Kafka high level api:  0.8.2.0

Comment: My *assumption* is that it is trying to reestablish connection somewhere and not backing off on unsuccessull attempts. I think you could dig into consumer fetch failure code to figure out the problem

Comment: where can i get the fetch failur code? From JMX metrics?

Comment: No no, I meant the actual consumer source code, not metrics. I wanted to say you could look through consumer code path that is triggered after unsuccessful fetches and see if there is some code block being retried too frequently or something. It is possible that there's a bug sitting somewhere there. But again, this is just my assumption.

Comment: it  show like a bug  aready  fix  int  0.9.0  [links](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3159)

Answer (score 3):

Increase in CPU utilisation for both kafka consumer and broker usually happens because of very  high frequency of poll requests from consumer. This mainly happens because of inefficient configuration for consumer.

**Check for two properties** :

1. **fetch.min.bytes** -> Minimum bytes to finish poll request
2. **fetch.max.wait.ms** -> Max wait at broker to finish poll request

If data in topic is not that frequently produced then keep fairly high value of **fetch.max.wait.ms** and non-zero value of **fetch.min.bytes** to avoid frequent poll requests to broker

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by upgrading kafka from:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>            
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```